# How to map a stored package function in iBatis?

Tags: ibatis

I am presently using

```
<parameterMap class="map" id="param1">
    <parameter property="result" jdbcType="BOOLEAN" javaType="boolean" mode="OUT"/>
    <parameter property="arg1" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="resultCode" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="int" mode="OUT"/>
</parameterMap>

<procedure id="contAvail" parameterMap="param1">
    <![CDATA[
        { ? = call pkg.func(?,?)}
    ]]>
</procedure>
```

what is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is nothing wrong with the code above. It works if we change the return data type from boolean to anything else. It seems boolean is not supported properly.

Also as Jim rightfully suggested, CDATA is not imp. It works with or without it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two parameters in your CALL but a parameterMap with three parameters.  You have one result but no resultMap.

Not sure if the CDATA hurts anything, but it shouldn't be needed.

See the [online help](http://ibatis.apache.org/onlinehelp.html) for details.  Also check out [this](http://andriusm.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/ibatis-and-stored-oracle-proceduresfunctions/) and [this](http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-stored-procedure-with-ibatis.html).

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note is that ibatis returns the result in the input parameter map itself even for function call.  In this case param1 will hold the result of the function call (and null is returned in the java method queryForObject()..)